# Images not showing in TableViewCells until it scroll-down

Tags: ios, parsing, uitableview, uiimage

I am querying my parse database to download images from a specific table.
Everything is working except there is what I reckon is a glitch.

The images only appear when I scroll the `UITableView` a little bit.

Yes I am downloading the images asynchronously.

Cheers

**UPDATE**

```
PFQuery *imageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"WallImageObject"];
    //[imageQuery orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
    [imageQuery whereKey:@"geoPoint" nearGeoPoint:currentLocationInGeoPoint withinKilometers:3.0];
    NSLog(@"PFGeoPoint current location: %f and %f", currentLocationInGeoPoint.latitude, currentLocationInGeoPoint.longitude);
    [imageQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error retreiving images: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else
        {
            for (PFObject *wallImageObject in objects) {
                WallImage *wallImage = [[WallImage alloc] init];
                wallImage.fbID = wallImageObject[@"UserId"];
                wallImage.username = wallImageObject[@"userName"];
                wallImage.createdAt = wallImageObject.createdAt;

                [[NSOperationQueue pffileOperationQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    wallImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[(PFFile *)wallImageObject[@"image"] getData]];
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:N_ImageDownloaded object:nil];
                }];

                wallImage.imageID = wallImageObject.objectId;
                wallImage.geoPoint = wallImageObject[@"geoPoint"];
                NSLog(@"Image latitude: %f and londitude %f", wallImage.geoPoint.latitude, wallImage.geoPoint.longitude);
                [[DataStore instance].wallImages addObject:wallImage];
            }
            NSLog(@"%lu images in this location", (unsigned long)[[DataStore instance].wallImages count]);
            if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(communicationDidGetWallImages:)]) {
                [delegate communicationDidGetWallImages:YES];
            }
        }
```

**And here where I display the images**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Post";
    FeedPhotoCell *feedPhotoCell = (FeedPhotoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    WallImage *wallImage = [DataStore instance].wallImages[indexPath.row];

    [feedPhotoCell.photoPost setImage:wallImage.image];

    NSString *facebbokUserID = wallImage.fbID;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",facebbokUserID];
    NSURL *facebookProfilePicURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    [feedPhotoCell.profilePhoto setImageWithURL:facebookProfilePicURL];
    feedPhotoCell.profilePhoto.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    feedPhotoCell.profilePhoto.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    feedPhotoCell.profilePhoto.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    feedPhotoCell.profilePhoto.clipsToBounds = YES;

    NSLog(@"image cell height: %f", feedPhotoCell.photoPost.image.size.height);

    return feedPhotoCell;
}
```

Comment: If possible, it would help to provide the code that you use to download and display the images.

Comment: It sounds like you're setting the images on a background thread. You may have to dispatch `imageView.image = ...` onto the main thread to make changes effective before the table view redraws itself.

Comment: I fixed it, following what you told. I start download the images in the cellForRowAtIndex and when it comes the response I load the image onto the main thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the images use up a lot of memory, they will be removed to free up memory.

Then, when your table view tries to draw them, it has to download them again, which takes time.

The solution is to download the image to the disk on the phone, and then load the images from the files on disk.

Comment: Its not like the data is being reloaded. If I don't scroll the table at all, the images do not show up. However, if I slightly scroll the table the images show.